# What is the simplest way to add a hyperlink to a canvas element in ReportLab?

Tags: python, canvas, hyperlink, reportlab

I am using ReportLab to make a pdf using Python.  I want to add a shape to the canvas, and have that shape act as a hyperlink.  What is the simplest way to make the rectangle in the following example link to google.com?

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")

# move the origin up and to the left, draw square
c.translate(inch,9*inch)
# How do I make this rectangle link to google.com?
c.rect(inch,inch,1*inch,1*inch, fill=1)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call `linkURL` on the Canvas:

```
c.linkURL('http://google.com', (inch, inch, 2*inch, 2*inch), relative=1)
```

The rectangle is the clickable area, so you'd have to match that to the drawn rectangle. The arguments are two coordinates, twice `x, y` for the bottom-left and top-right corner.

See more examples in this blog post: http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/adding-links-to-pdf/

Comment: Most probably @MartjinPieters is not aware of the issue highlighted by two other answers. Please refer to Crebits's answer for the amended approach.

Comment: @fatih_dur: thanks for the heads-up, I was not aware of the other posts indeed.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the Martijn answer, the linkURL draw a rectangle using the "default" coordinate system, i.e., bottom+up/left+right. Since the default canvas use the top down coord, i suggest you to make a quick fix basing on your canvas height.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness... you can use `canvas.linkURL()`, but keep in mind that the `rect` coordinates expected in `linkURL` **are not like** the ones in `canvas.rect()`.

So, if you want to use `linkURL` over a previously drawn `rect`, it'll be like this:

```
c.rect(x, y, w, h)                # rect uses width and height
c.linkURL(url, (x, y, x+w, y+h))  # linkURL uses the end point's x and y
```

I got quite confused at this until I realized (I was getting weird overlaps and big linked areas everywhere).